# Integration exercise: $ \int \frac{e^{5x}}{ (e^{2x} - e^x - 20) }dx$

Tags: integration

I have trouble integrating:

$$ \int \frac{e^{5x}}{e^{2x} - e^x - 20} dx$$

With $t=e^x$, I've rewritten it as:

$$\int \frac{t^5}{t^2 - t - 20} \frac{1}{t} dt$$

Then I tried *integration by parts*, but I am not any closer to the solution.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/627383/23353

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$$\int \frac{t^5}{t^2 - t - 20} \frac{1}{t} dt$$
$$\int \frac{t^4}{t^2 - t - 20} dt$$
try to make proper fraction
$$\int (t^2+t+21)+\frac{41t+420}{t^2 - t - 20} dt$$
$$\int (t^2+t+21)\;dt+\int \frac{41t+420}{t^2 - t - 20} dt$$
first integration is basic and for second use [partial fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction)
$$\dfrac{t^3}{3}+\dfrac{t^2}{2}+21t+\int \dfrac {625}{9(t-5)}-\dfrac{256}{9(t+4)}\;\;dt$$
$$\dfrac{t^3}{3}+\dfrac{t^2}{2}+21t+\dfrac {625}{9}\log (t-5)-\dfrac{256}{9}\log (t+4)$$
put $t=e^x$
$$\mathbf {Answer}=\dfrac{e^{3x}}{3}+\dfrac{e^{2x}}{2}+21e^x+\dfrac {625}{9}\log (e^x-5)-\dfrac{256}{9}\log (e^x+4)+C\;$$
solution of partial fraction used above
$$\dfrac{41t+420}{t^2 - t - 20}=\dfrac {A}{t-5}+\dfrac{B}{t+4}$$
$${41t+420}={A}(t+4)+B({t-5})$$
put $t=5$ and then $t=-4$
$${41\times 5+420}={A}(5+4)+B({5-5})$$
$$A=\dfrac {625}{9}$$
$${41\times (-4)+420}={A}(-4+4)+B({-4-5})$$
$$B=\dfrac {-256}{9}$$
$$\dfrac{41t+420}{t^2 - t - 20}=\dfrac {625}{9(t-5)}-\dfrac{256}{9(t+4)}$$

Comment: @amWhy thanks :D

Comment: u r welcome! ;-)

Comment: I get $41t + 420$ as the remainder.

Comment: I am absolutely sure that the $41t - 420$ is wrong.

Comment: @klaufir you are right

Answer (score 5):

Hint: why not try using synthetic division on this expression to get the sum of a polynomial expression and a remainder term? Then you can integrate using the power rule and apply partial fractions decomposition to the remainder.